# LIKE query in sqlite3

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I was doing practice on w3 schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/exercise.asp?filename=exercise_wildcards2

Here the query is: Select all records where the first letter of the City is an "a" or a "c" or an "s".

But when I run the same query on my local device with sqlite3 (with similar table), it displayed nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE city LIKE '[acs]%';
```

Please feel free to ask me for more details regarding this problem and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support an enhanced `LIKE` operator which supports the syntax you are using (though SQL Server does).  SQLite *does* support the `REGEXP` operator, but it needs to be loaded.  However, we can phrase your query using `LIKE` as follows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE city LIKE 'a%' OR city LIKE 'c%' OR city LIKE 's%';
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite supports the [`GLOB`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators) operator which uses the Unix file globbing syntax for its wildcards:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE city GLOB '[acs]*';
```